# How to control four decimal values to two from database money field c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, decimal

[image]I want to append the dataSource to dataGridvIew from database which is having money fields as [image]

Here `nrdc_ItemPrice` and `nrdc_Lntotl` fields are appending to datagridview as shown in 1st image

How can I control them to .00 values. Here is my code

```
dsEstmDtls = salesDCCls.ordrAckDataSet(estmID);
dtDCDtls = dsEstmDtls.Tables[1];
dgvDcNon.DataSource = dtDCDtls;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `DataGridView` column format :

```
dgvDcNon.Columns["ColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

You can do that from the designer as well. Example from the web :

[image]